# What is the Pythonic way to ID when in a bytestring values stop being in a particular range?

Tags: python-3.x

I need a function which takes a bytestring of length n, and returns only those first m bytes that can be decoded into the Latin1 character set. (I am writing a translator for a very old file format, and one of the fields providing a human readable label is—unlike much of the rest of the file format—of fixed length, so after the human readable name, there's a byte character that is either less than b'\x20'—space—or greater than b'\xe7'—tilde—and then uninitialized byte values for the remainder of the fixed field.)

Currently I make do thus:

```
n = 27
def extract_name(bytestring):
  for i in range(0,n):
    if (bytestring[i:i+1]<b' ') or (bytestring[i:i+1]>b'~'):
      name_length = i
      break
    else:
      name_length = n
  name = bytestring[0:name_length].decode('Latin1')
  return name
```

This works:

```
>>>my_string = b'My Great Name\xf0\x1e\x23\x23\xe1\x06\xbc\x1b\x8a\xf7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>>extract_name(my_string)
'My Great Name'
```

However, I feel clunky about the code, and wonder if I can make it more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regular expressions are your friend!**

```
import re
def extract_name(bytestring):
  return re.sub(b'[\x00-\x1f].*|[\x7f-\xff].*', b'', bytestring).decode('Latin1')
```

This gives the desired behavior:

```
>>>my_string = b'My Great Name\xf0\x1e\x23\x23\xe1\x06\xbc\x1b\x8a\xf7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>>extract_name(my_string)
'My Great Name'
```